# How to fit experimental data in Python to inverse trigonometric function with limited definition area using scipy.curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy, trigonometry, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit some experimental data to a nonlinear function with one parameter that includes an arcus cosine function which therefore is limited in its area of definition from -1 to 1. I use scipy's curve_fit to find the parameter of the function, but it returns the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 400.
```

The function I want to fit is this one:

```
def fitfunc(x, a):
    y = np.rad2deg(np.arccos(x*np.cos(np.deg2rad(a))))
    return y
```

For the fitting, I provid a numpy array for x and y respectively which contain values in degree (which is why the function contains conversion to and from radians).

```
param, param_cov = curve_fit(fitfunc, xs, ys)
```

When I use other fit functions like for example a polynomial, the curve_fit returns some values, the error mentioned above only occurs when I use this function which includes an arcus cosine.

I suspect that it cannot fit the data points because depending on the parameter of the arcus cosine function, some data points do not lie inside the area of definition of the arcus cosine. I have tried raising the number iterations (maxfev) but without success.

Sample data:

```
ys = np.array([113.46125, 129.4225, 140.88125, 145.80375, 145.4425, 
              146.97125, 97.8025, 112.91125, 114.4325, 119.16125, 
              130.13875, 134.63125, 129.4375, 141.99, 139.86, 
              138.77875, 137.91875, 140.71375])

xs = np.array([2.786427013, 3.325624466, 3.473013087, 3.598247534, 4.304280248,
               4.958273121, 2.679526725, 2.409388637, 2.606306639, 3.661558062,
               4.569923009, 4.836843789, 3.377013596, 3.664550526, 4.335401233,
               3.064199519, 3.97155254, 4.100567011])
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data so that we can attempt to reproduce your error?

Comment: I edited the post with the sample data.

Comment: If you run just the `fitfunc` like `y=fitfunc(xs, 60)`, you get the invalid value warning again. That's because `np.arccos` only accepts values in the range [-1, 1]. So I'd think you'd have to try some normalization of your data in order to be able to get it to fit.

Comment: Additionally, since your `fitfunc` accepts a parameter `a`, you have to provide `curve_fit` with an initial guess. Something like `params = [60]`, then `param, param_cov = curve_fit(fitfunc, xs, ys, p0=params)`.

Answer (score 3):

As [HS-nebula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10852841/hs-nebula?tab=profile) mentioned in his comments, you need to define an initial value `a0` of `a` as a start guess for the curve-fitting. Moreover, you need to be careful when choosing `a0` as your `np.arcos()` is only defined in [-1,1] and choosing the wrong `a0` results in error.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

ys = np.array([113.46125,  129.4225, 140.88125, 145.80375,  145.4425, 146.97125,  
                 97.8025, 112.91125,  114.4325, 119.16125, 130.13875, 134.63125,
                129.4375,    141.99,    139.86, 138.77875, 137.91875, 140.71375])

xs = np.array([2.786427013, 3.325624466, 3.473013087, 3.598247534, 4.304280248, 4.958273121, 
               2.679526725, 2.409388637, 2.606306639, 3.661558062, 4.569923009, 4.836843789,
               3.377013596, 3.664550526, 4.335401233, 3.064199519, 3.97155254, 4.100567011])

def fit_func(x, a):
    a_in_rad         = np.deg2rad(a)
    cos_a_in_rad     = np.cos(a_in_rad)
    arcos_xa_product = np.arccos( x * cos_a_in_rad )
    return np.rad2deg(arcos_xa_product)

a0 = 80
param, param_cov = curve_fit(fit_func, xs, ys, a0, bounds = (0, 360))
print('Using curve we retrieve a value of a = ', param[0])
```

Output:

```
Using curve we retrieve a value of a =  100.05275506147824
```

However if you choose `a0=60`, you get the following error:

> ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point.

To be able to use the data with all possible values of `a`, a normalization as [HS-nebula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10852841/hs-nebula?tab=profile) suggested is good idea.